# Sum of two integrals is zero

Tags: integration, reflection

this sum is said to be equal to $0$:
$\int_{\mathbb{R}}\int_{-\infty}^x \frac{h(x)h(t)}{t-x}dt dx +\int_{\mathbb{R}}\int_{x}^{\infty} \frac{h(x)h(t)}{t-x}dt dx$
and I'm trying to understand why.

As reason I got said "because of reflection" but I still don't see it.

So I tried something:

$\int_{\mathbb{R}}\int_{-\infty}^x \frac{h(x)h(t)}{t-x}dt dx +\int_{\mathbb{R}}\int_{x}^{\infty} \frac{h(x)h(t)}{t-x}dt dx$

$=\int_{\mathbb{R}}\int_{-\infty}^x \frac{h(x)h(t)}{t-x}dt dx -\int_{\mathbb{R}}\int_{x}^{\infty} \frac{h(x)h(t)}{x-t}dt dx$

where I changed the sign of the second integral and therefore, I swapped $x$ and $t$ in the denominator.

$=\int_{\mathbb{R}}\int_{-\infty}^x \frac{h(x)h(t)}{t-x}dt dx +\int_{\mathbb{R}}\int_{\infty}^{x} \frac{h(x)h(t)}{x-t}dt dx$

where I swapped the integrationbounds of the second integral and therefore, the sign changes again.

$=\int_{\mathbb{R}}\int_{-\infty}^x \frac{h(x)h(t)}{t-x}dt dx -\int_{\mathbb{R}}\int_{\infty}^{x} \frac{h(x)h(t)}{t-x}dt dx$

where I swapped $t$ and $x$ in the denominator of the second integral back again and therefore, the sign of the second integral is negative again.

Did I do a mistake? I don't see why this should be equal to $0$, since in the second integral we have $\infty$ and $x$ as integrationbounds and in the first $-\infty$ and $x$ or should it also be $-\infty$ in the second integral?

Really thankful for any help!!

Comment: Lebesgue integrals or what?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If the integrand is Lebesgue integrable then you can write the sum also as
$$
\int_{\Bbb R ^2}\frac{h(x)h(t)}{t-x}\,\mathrm d (x,t)=\int_{x>t}\frac{h(x)h(t)}{t-x}\,\mathrm d (x,t)+\int_{x<t}\frac{h(x)h(t)}{t-x}\,\mathrm d (x,t)\\
=\int_{x<t}\frac{h(x)h(t)}{|t-x|}\,\mathrm d (x,t)+\int_{x>t}\frac{h(x)h(t)}{-|t-x|}\,\mathrm d (x,t)\\
=\int_{x<t}\frac{h(x)h(t)}{|t-x|}\,\mathrm d (x,t)-\int_{x>t}\frac{h(x)h(t)}{|t-x|}\,\mathrm d (x,t)
$$
Now note that the last two integrals are exactly the same integral because $x$ and $t$ are tags that can be interchanged, so the final result is zero.